# How to get length of string using Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

In a table I have columns `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME`. I have to concatenate the two names and retrieve names containing more than 12 characters.

I tried the following query:

```
select *
from   (select first_name, last_name 
        from customer as name
       )
where  length(NAME) = 12
```

Comment: You aren't concatenating columns `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` in your query.

Comment: My solution in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=368920a0e08d4ce70b9cf111dfa720b1)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * 
from (
  select first_name||last_name as name 
  from customer 
)
where length(name)>12
```

Answer (score 1):

You need only one SELECT

```
SELECT first_name || last_name AS name
  FROM customer
 WHERE LENGTH(first_name||last_name) > 12
```

Optionally TRIM name and last_name from spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm writing from my phone. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating the first name and last name.
Also no need to write an inline view, below is the query.

```
select FIRST_NAME || LAST_NAME as NAME 
from   CUSTOMER
where  length(FIRST_NAME || LAST_NAME) > 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you rewrite your question to check if the total length of first name and last name is more than 12, you probably get a different response from people with a more efficient code. It is not necessary to make Oracle actually concatenate the columns.

Programmers are too literal these days. :)